# ExecutionPolicy undefined- Python and Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, executionpolicy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIUFv.png)I'm learning Python using Visual Studio Code. I'm getting the ExecutionPolicy angry red text.  I've opened Windows Powershell as an Admin. Typed the code: "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted". I still have undefined ExecutionPolicy for MachinePolicy and UserPolicy. So I tried "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted"...that didn't go well, lol.  I'd appreciate guidance.

'''(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Execution Policy Change
The execution policy helps protect you from scripts that you do not trust. Changing the execution policy might expose
you to the security risks described in the about_Execution_Policies help topic at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. Do you want to change the execution policy?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): A
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of Bypass. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more
information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], SecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionPolicyOverride,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> protractor conf.js
protractor : The term 'protractor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- protractor conf.js
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protractor:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy UnrestrictedSet-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot bind parameter 'ExecutionPolicy'. Cannot convert value "UnrestrictedSet-ExecutionPolicy"
to type "Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name
UnrestrictedSet-ExecutionPolicy to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try
again:
Unrestricted, RemoteSigned, AllSigned, Restricted, Default, Bypass, Undefined"
At line:1 char:57

- ...  CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy UnrestrictedSet-ExecutionPolicy -Scope  ...
- ```
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], ParameterBindingException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricte ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantSetGroupPolicy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope UserPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must
be set through Group Policy.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope UserPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CantSetGroupPolicy,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
  ```

(base) PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

```
    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
```

MachinePolicy       Undefined
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process          Bypass
CurrentUser    Unrestricted
LocalMachine    RemoteSigned'''